# Making a conditional loop condition?

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

I would like to create a while loop where it will keep running under one of two conditions, where the one chosen is determined as a conditional. For example, it would be something along the lines of `while(if (c = true) a<b else b<a)`. Is there any simple syntax for this? Or would I have to go the brute way and do the following?

```
if (c = true) 
{ 
   while(a<b)
   {
   }
} 
else 
{
   while(b<a)
   {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take advantage of the short-circuit nature of boolean evaluations, and:

```
while ((c && a < b) || (!c && b < a)) {
    // ...
}
```

However, you might find this is difficult to read. Another approach might be to use the conditional operator:

```
while (c ? (a < b) : (b < a)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: that will only do it if c toggles to false during the loop.  What he has is probably the best he's going to get. Edit - oooh, you covered both conditions.  didnt see that.  tricky 1 letter variables.

Comment: Ah, this is perfect (and not difficult to read either); thank you!

Comment: @Wug I have c set to a specific value before the loop is reached, so with the syntax he provided, there would be no need to toggle it mid-loop; this is what I needed.

Comment: I read it as one loop that operated on one condition.  didn't see that the a and b of the second condition was flipped.

Comment: @ASpirin: The inverse of `a < b` is `b <= a`, which isn't the same as `b < a`.

Comment: @aspirin: (!!c ^ (b < a)) might behave better,

Comment: @Greg Hewgill you are right, c ^ (b < a) not working, because a == b not have been discarded

Comment: Note that with this solution you always have the evaluation of the toggle condition in the loop condition. The "if while else while" approach doesn't have that and may be slightly faster.

Comment: @Wormbo: If `c` isn't changed within the loop, any good compiler optimiser will see that and only make that decision once, and compile code equivalent to the "if while else while" code.

Comment: I have yet to see the CLR JIT compiler do such an optimization at runtime. And as far as I can tell, the C# compiler doesn't optimize such conditions away at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is:

```
while( c && a<b || !c && b<a )
{
  ...
}
```

Apologies if I haven't got my C# syntax correct.  I'm a C++ junkie. =)